# Yii Pagination Variables from DataProvider

Tags: yii

I need certain pagination variables in my controller action.

such as:

1.Current Page Number

2.Current Page offset

3.total records displayed

***i.e. 31 to 40 of 2005 records displayed***

I tried the following:

```
$dataProvider = NodesTerms::getNodesDataFromTerms($nodeId) ;     
  $pagination = $dataProvider->getPagination();
  var_dump($pagination->getPageCount());
  //var_dump($pagination->currentPage);
```

I can get the Pagination Object, but zero (0) in `$pagination->currentPage`  or `$pagination->offset` etc....

I need this information to dynamically generate meta page `title` and `description` on actions with page listings such as pagetitle:  page 3 of 10 for American Recipes...

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: have you used a `CPagination` object in the `getNodesDataFromTerms` function? if yes what's the config for it? if not, then first you'll need that

Comment: Using SQL Data Provider. Here's what returns from NodesTerms::getNodesDataFromTerms($nodeId).

   $dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
         'keyField'=>'node_id',
         'totalItemCount'=>$count,
         'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>10)));  
    
   return $dataProvider ;

Comment: Since i'm passing the 'pagination' key in DataProvider, i assume it shall create the pagination object.

Comment: Please show code where you create CActiveDataProvider

Comment: Sorry i'm not on my pc right now, will post the code in a few hours.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Here's the code where data provider is being created: http://pastebin.com/98db6x0u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the [`itemCount`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#itemCount-detail) explicitly in your `dataProvider`:

```php
'pagination'=>array(
    'pageSize'=>10,
    'itemCount'=>$count
)
```

Or use a new `CPagination` object:

```php
$pagination = new CPagination($count);

$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    // ... other config
    'pagination' => $pagination
));
```

---

How this works:

The pagination's `itemCount` is set during creation of the data-provider and again [in `CSqlDataProvider`'s `fetchData`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/CSqlDataProvider.php#L95) function:

```php
    $pagination->setItemCount($this->getTotalItemCount());
```

During creation of data-provider only the values passed to the `pagination` property are used, and if we don't pass `itemCount` value, then the default of `0` is used.
So if we want to access `offset` or `pageCount` or `currentPage` or `itemCount` **before** the call to `fetchData` we have to set the `itemCount` explicitly.

However if we want those values after the call to `fetchData` then the values are already correctly populated due to the call to `setItemCount` within `fetchData`.

An example for clarity (without passing `itemCount` during data-provider creation):

```php
$dataProvider = NodesTerms::getNodesDataFromTerms($nodeId);     
$pagination = $dataProvider->getPagination();
var_dump($pagination->getPageCount()); // this will be zero

$data=$dataProvider->getData(); // getData calls fetchData()

var_dump($pagination->getPageCount()); // now this will be correct value
```

Comment: Perfect buddy... Just passing 'itemCount' as you say. i can now get $pagination->currentPage and $pagination->getOffset() easily... 

Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.

Comment: glad to help out, i will be adding more of an explanation in sometime, which should help in understanding this solution better

Comment: Yes i'll be waiting for some explanation if possible. If i was already passing totalItemCount in the CSQLDataProvider as the documentation say as necessary, then why it was needed to pass itemCount inside the pagination instance.  This thing is nowhere in documentation or may be i overlooked if such information is available.

Comment: yeah, it isn't mentioned anywhere i had to dig into source :). anyway check back in 30 mins, kinda busy atm

Comment: Sure man, take your time. It's around 2 AM at my timezone. going to sleep will read your comment in the morning... take care.

Comment: Your explanation makes a great deal of sense. Thanks a lot for your time. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

getCurrentPage returns "the zero-based index of the current page"

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#getCurrentPage-detail

so if you're on the first page, it should be returning 0.

And as you know the page size and the total number of records that will be enough for you to generate your page title.

Comment: It returns 0 even i'm on page 2,3,4 etc.  Actually i am rewriting a site in yii and i need exact same meta title n description as of old site i am porting from. Need page x of y for american recipes. And for meta description as x to y of z total recipes displayed. This means i need page nos as well as record offset for current page.

Comment: Just wanna say thanks for taking time for the answer. Appreciate it.