# yii gridview does not display all the data from its respective table

Tags: php, sql, gridview, yii

i have this query using CActiveDataProvider. My table contains 15 records that satisfies the condition, but for some reason, only ten records are being displayed. What might be missing here.

```
$prov2 = new CActiveDataProvider('BaseSiReceivedItem', array(
            'criteria' => array(
            'condition' => 'iar_no = 0'
            )));

echo count($prov2->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'pagination'=>array(
'pageSize'=>15,
)
```

Does that now show you 15?

This link about itemCounts may also be helpful. [Yii Pagination Variables from DataProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254524/yii-pagination-variables-from-dataprovider)

Comment: my page size is already set at 20.. but only shows 10 records

Comment: Please post some more code including model and the criteria so we can get a better picture. It's hard to tell from this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The listview widget's pageSize value in the view file might be overriding the pageSize value in the controller (if it's not set, the default value may override the controller).

Or, you could create a custom list view like this:

**extensions/CustomListView.php**

```
<?php
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CListView');

class CustomListView extends CListView {

    public function init() {
        if ($this->dataProvider !== null)
            $this->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 30;
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

and use it in your view: **views/{model}/index.php**

```
<?php $this->widget('CustomListView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => '_view'
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also encountered this problem , listing only 10 items while disabling pagination from my list view. At that time I used the following code and I got all the items listed :)

```
$data = new CActiveDataProvider('ProviderPortfolioSet', array('criteria' => $criteria, 'pagination' => false));
```